# Running a Phantomjs script as a gruntjs Task

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs

I have a script that I run in phantomjs that performs some tasks in a web browser. I normally run it like so:

```
phantomjs build.js
```

How would I integrate this as a Task in a Gruntjs build?

i'm currently using the `grunt-shell` plugin however I cannot see the output from phamtomjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the stdout option if you want to see the output logged.

```
shell: {
    phantom: {
        command: 'phantomjs build.js',
        options: {
            stdout: true
        }
    }
}
```